# Why does sha1 return a different hash for the same input string?

Tags: c, hash, sha1

This is a very simple program that takes a integer and converts it to a string. From there I hash the string using SHA1 and print the hash to the console. But when I rerun the program, I get a different hash for the same integer that was defined in my program. Any idea why this is happening and how could I fix it?

This is my program. To compile I use: `gcc -o myhash myhash.c -lcrypto`

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    //sha1 returns 20 byte hash
    unsigned char myHash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    //my integer that I want to hash
    int myInt = -1613543;

    //convert to char string
    char input[50]; 
    snprintf(input,50,"%d",myInt);

    //compute hash
    SHA1(input,sizeof(input),myHash);

    //print hash
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++){

        printf("%02x", myHash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: security.se is not for debugging your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your SHA-1 calculation includes garbage memory.

```
char input[50]; 
snprintf(input,50,"%d",myInt);
```

Here you initialize a few bytes at the beginning, terminated by `\0`. But the trailing memory is not initialized. You could do this by using an explicit array initializer (`char input[50] = { 0 };`) or by calling `memset(input, 0, sizeof(input))`.

```
//compute hash
SHA1(input,sizeof(input),myHash);
```

Here you calculate the SHA-1 hash over the full 50-byte input. Perhaps you want to use `strlen(input)` instead of `sizeof(input)`?

Finally a hint: use a known working tool as reference. For instance:

```
$ echo -n -1613543 | sha1sum 
e3f0005827c95440fb6a9045b400d3b2d64001f8  -
$ echo -n -1613543 | openssl sha1
(stdin)= e3f0005827c95440fb6a9045b400d3b2d64001f8
```